# Referring to a movieclip from within another movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, visibility

At a certain keyframe of a videoclip (called videos_mc), I want to change the visibility of another movieclip (called fundoMenu_mc). These two movie clips are nested in the same scene.

When I try:

```
videos_mc(parent).fundoMenu_mc.visible = false;
```

I get this error:

> 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method videos_mc.

When I try:

```
this.parent.fundoMenu_mc.visible = false;
```

I get this error:

> 1119: Access of possibly undefined property fundoMenu_mc through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If both MovieClips are in the same scene and fundoMenu_mc within the videos_mc MovieClip, try this

```
videos_mc.fundoMenu_mc.visible = false;
```

If referring from an another Movieclip

```
 MovieClip(parent).videos_mc.fundoMenu_mc.visible
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
MovieClip(parent).fundoMenu_mc.visible = false;
```